# Meteor - find return undefined

Tags: mongodb, meteor, find

I work on meteor with mongodb. I am trying to get a collection from database. I can insert data without any problem in this collection from meteor, but when I try to find, it doesn't works.
My collection is 'first'.

Server side:

```
Meteor.publish('first', function(){
  return first.find();
});
```

Client side:

```
var datacollab = first.find({"Mois":"Mars"});
console.log("collab: " + datacollab);
```

When I make this command line in mongo shell, it works fine.
I already try to change my request with findOne, or put .fetch at the end.

Comment: You did not specify whether you subscribe or not?

Comment: Yes I did it in client side:
`Meteor.subscribe('first');`

Comment: Are you waiting for the subscription to be ready / for data to arrive?

Comment: I guess no, because I do first.find in Template.mytemplate.rendered. But if I do it in .event, it works. How can I wait for subscription to be ready in .rendered?? I need to load my data in .rendered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your code to be in your [`Template.myTemplate.onRendered`](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered) hook, then you have several options:

- Use a [`Tracker.autorun`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun) that will be automatically re-executed when your DB query / cursor returns new data.
- Use the [`onReady`](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html#Meteor-subscribe) callback of the subscription (assuming you subscribe either when template is created or rendered). Your callback will be executed when the client has received a first full snapshot of the server publication.

Comment: I try to use Tracker.autorun. I wrote:
`var handle = Meteor.subscribe('first');
Tracker.autorun(function() {
      if (handle.ready()){
        console.log('ready');
        var datacollab = first.find().fetch();
        console.log( "data = " + datacollab);
      }else{
        console.log('not ready');
      }
    });`
and the web console show me that I am not able to use my data, but if I wait a little bit more, it's okay:
[link](http://www.zupimages.net/up/17/16/s23s.tiff)

Comment: I guess it's another problem, your answer is right for my initial problem. Thanks